# Blazor Server IHttpContextAccessor returning null when deployed

Tags: blazor-server-side

I am dynamically setting the connection string based on the user that is logged in. This is working perfectly when running locally/debugging but when its deployed it's returning a null reference exception. This is my DbContext and I am handling the connection string logic in the OnConfigure method:

```
namespace SwordfishCRM.Services.ApplicationDbContext
{
    public class PrimaryApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        private readonly HttpContext context;
        private readonly IConfiguration configuration;

        public PrimaryApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<PrimaryApplicationDbContext> options, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, IConfiguration configuration) : base(options)
        {
            this.context = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
            this.configuration = configuration;
        }

        //Tables
        public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ChimneySweepCycle> ChimneySweepCycles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ChimneySweepMethod> ChimneySweepMethods { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ContactMethod> ContactMethods { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ContactPreference> ContactPreferences { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Diary> Diary { get; set; }
        public DbSet<DiaryDate> DiaryDates { get; set; }
        public DbSet<DiaryOption> DiaryOptions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Gender> Genders { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<JobActualLine> JobActualLines { get; set; }
        public DbSet<JobApproval> JobApprovals { get; set; }
        public DbSet<JobQuoteLine> JobQuoteLines { get; set; }
        public DbSet<JobStatus> JobStatuses { get; set; }
        public DbSet<JobType> JobTypes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Report> Reports { get; set; }
        public DbSet<RetroSweepingCertificate> RetroSweepingCertificates { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ScheduleDay> ScheduleDays { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ScheduleExceptionDay> ScheduleExceptionDays { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Title> Titles { get; set; }

        //Views
        public virtual DbSet<vwAvailableApoointment> vwAvailableApoointments { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder
                .Entity<vwAvailableApoointment>(eb =>
                {
                    eb.HasNoKey();
                    eb.ToView("vwAvailableApoointments");
                });
        }


        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            var userId = context.User.Identity.Name;
            if (userId == null)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("Master"));
            }
            else
            {
                var prefix = IdentitySupport.GetConnectionPrefix(userId);
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString(prefix));
            }        
        }
    }
}
```

This is the console error when it's been deployed:

```
Error: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at SwordfishCRM.Services.ApplicationDbContext.PrimaryApplicationDbContext.OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) in D:\a\1\s\SwordfishCRM.Services\ApplicationDbContext\PrimaryApplicationDbContext .cs:line 67
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_ContextServices()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_Model()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.get_EntityType()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.CheckState()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.get_EntityQueryable()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
   at System.Linq.Queryable.OrderBy[TSource,TKey](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 keySelector)
   at SwordfishCRM.Web.Pages.Swordfish.DiaryScheduleExceptionDates.OnInitializedAsync() in D:\a\1\s\SwordfishCRM.Web\Pages\Swordfish\DiaryScheduleExceptionDates.razor:line 25
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()
```

I am confused why this run's locally but not when deployed. I would welcome any support.
Thank you

I have tried different variations of HTTPContext but to no avail. I am expecting it to find the logged in user, so I can retrieve a code to set the connection string.
There is a fail safe to use the config for the Master database (this is not the actual Master database, just a name for the main database with all the users etc...)
There is a step before this that if they are not logged in, they wont even hit this screen.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out I needed AuthenticationStateProvider, then I needed to place a wait until the the prefix was returned. This is working a treat!!

```
protected override async void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            var authstate = await authenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
            var userId = authstate.User;
            if (userId == null)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("Master"));
            }
            else
            {
                var prefix = IdentitySupport.GetConnectionPrefix(userId.Identity.Name);
                await Task.CompletedTask;
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString(prefix));
            }        
        }
```